# How to decide how many n_neighbors to consider while implementing LocalOutlierFactor?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, outlier, hyperparameter-tuning, k-nn

I have a data set with rows: 134000 and columns: 200. I am trying to identify the outliers in data set using [`LocalOutlierFactor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.LocalOutlierFactor.html) from scikit-learn. Although I understand how the algorithm works, I am unable to decide `n_neighbors` for my data set.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Use grid search to find the optimal number of neighbors

Comment: This paper may be of interest: [Automatic Hyperparameter Tuning Method for Local Outlier Factor, with Applications to Anomaly Detection](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.00567.pdf) (Feb 5, 2019)

Comment: This answer might be helpful https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138675/choosing-a-k-value-for-local-outlier-factor-lof-detection-analysis Describes how to choose the n_neighbors based on the linked paper.

Answer (score 2):

One normally uses Grid Search for calculating the optimum parameters in these situations:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import numpy as np

n = 30 # Max number of neighbours you want to consider
param_grid = {'n_neighbors': np.arange(n)}
grid = GridSearchCV(KNeighborsClassifier(), param_grid)
```

Then given this grid, you can fit it to your data to compute its optimum values (from those you provided, they may not be *global* optima (or even local if the returned value is one of the extrema of your input range)):

```
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

You can view the optimum parameters from your input by calling:

```
grid.best_params_
>>> {'n_neighbors': ?}
```

You can automatically select an estimator with said optimum parameters by calling:

```
model = grid.best_estimator_
y_pred = model.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
```

Note: you can find the optimum values of other parameters by adding them to the input dictionary `param_grid`.

Comment: I think the question asks about how many neighbours to choose in the LocalOutlierFactor data pre-processor, not in applying the KNearestNeighbors Classifier. It is a more difficult problem in that Outlier Detection is in general an unsupervised task.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I finally tried this on my data set. Although consuming entire training data set for grid search was taking too much time that why I used n = 300 samples for grid search. I get the best_estimator as 2. What does best_estimator indicate? I am clueless. I looked up internet for grid search and its for hyper tuning.

Comment: @NehaBhushan `best_estimator_` returns the estimator you input automatically loaded with the optimum parameters. You can use it the same way you would use the estimator expicitly, e.g. `best_estimator_` is the same as `KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=best_params_['n_neighbors'])`